# Problem with definition of Kubernetes Ingress in helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy the following Ingress with helm:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    io.ctl.cd/ssl: "ui.releasename"
  name: ui
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
spec:
  rules:
    {{ if eq .Values.nodeSelector.location "minikube" }}
    - host: ui.{{ .Release.Namespace  }}.minikube.test
    {{ else }}
    - host: ui.{{ .Release.Namespace  }}.devhost
    {{ end }}
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: api
            servicePort: {{ .Values.api.service.port }}
          path: /
```

And I'm getting the following error 
    Error: `release x-**** failed: Ingress in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Ingress: only encoded map or array can be decoded into a struct`

I have a very similar ingress that is working fine, I don't don't want is happening with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in this string:

```
chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
```

For test, try:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    io.ctl.cd/ssl: "ui.releasename"
  name: ui
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}"
spec:
  rules:
    {{ if eq .Values.nodeSelector.location "minikube" }}
    - host: ui.{{ .Release.Namespace  }}.minikube.test
    {{ else }}
    - host: ui.{{ .Release.Namespace  }}.devhost
    {{ end }}
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: api
            servicePort: {{ .Values.api.service.port }}
          path: /
```

Comment: That line is extremely typical in Helm charts; Helm will reformat it to something like `chart: "x-0.1.0"`.